# C# creating stream object by using statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, io

I have one method to download s3 file

Method

```
Public ActionResult download(string filename, string credentials)
{
  ....
  Using(stream res = response from s3)
  { 
       return file(res, type, filename);
   }
}
```

But exception is throwing on executing the above method.

> Exception message -  The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly

I have to release the stream 'res' object after download.

Comment: What is `response from s3`?

Comment: Zip file with size of 50 mb

Comment: No, no, no, what exactly is the method/function/object/datatype/whatever?

Comment: It is bytes, we converting byte to stream to download in browser

Comment: No it isn't that would be a syntax error. Look, I'm trying to figure out why you are getting this error but if you won't show the actual code, I cannot help.

Comment: Without the "using" statement it is working perfectly but the stream object is not released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the `File` method for returning an `ActionResult`, you are **transferring** responsibility for closing the stream to the action-result, so indeed you **do not** want to call `Dispose` or use `using`. This is so that the `ActionResult` does not need to buffer the  data. So: just take out the `using`:

```
public ActionResult Download(string filename, string credentials)
{
  ....
  var res = /* response from s3 */
  return File(res, type, filename);
}
```

If you have non-trivial code, you can make it more complex:

```
public ActionResult Download(string filename, string credentials)
{
  ....
  Stream disposeMe = null;
  try {
      // ...
      disposeMe = /* response from s3 */
      // ...
      var result = File(disposeMe, type, filename);    
      disposeMe = null; // successfully created File result which
                        // now owns the stream, so *leave stream open*
      return result;
  } finally {
      disposeMe?.Dispose(); // if not handed over, dispose
  }
}
```

Comment: will the  'File' method close the stream 'res' object, when it is no longer needed

Comment: yes; in this approach you are transferring lifetime/ownership to the action result